# OpenOCD stuck listening on ports

Tags: microcontroller, port, openocd, maxim

I have a fresh install of Maxims Micros SDK and I am having an issue when I try to debug or even run on target. I get the following output on the eclipse console, it never gets past this listening step. This is only the case on windows 11. On a windows 10 machine it works fine.  Not sure it maybe this fresh windows 11 install is missing something openOCD or eclipse assumes is present. The lack of error output messages does not help

```
    Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0+dev-g4f85f7914 (2021-12-16-13:53)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
DEPRECATED! use 'adapter driver' not 'interface'
DEPRECATED! use 'adapter srst delay' not 'adapter_nsrst_delay'
DEPRECATED! use 'adapter srst pulse_width' not 'adapter_nsrst_assert_width'
Started by GNU MCU Eclipse
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
```

This was not the issue a few weeks ago, I now have a fresh windows install. When I plug the MCU i get the DAPLINK removable drive pop up for drag-drop firmware but cmsis_dap debugging seems to not be working at least thats what I can gather, or somehow openocd version is too new than what the script in eclipse was written for.
This is what eclipse script for debug and run configurations has:

```
-s ${env_var:TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/OpenOCD/scripts -f  interface/cmsis-dap.cfg -f target/max32670.cfg
```

Comment: failure caused by a fresh windows install usually means a missing driver

Comment: I also had trouble getting Eclipse IDE to debug the first time... had a conf call with a colleague at analog(maxim), but Eclipse updated just as the call began. Try hunting at Eclipse(2019-09) -> Project Explorer -> myProject -> Right-Click menu -> Debug As... -> **Debug Configurations** (dialog box).  In the tree view GDB OpenOCD Debugging, select myProject , then Debugger tab | OpenOCD Setup | Config options: `-s ${env_var:TOOLCHAIN_PATH}/OpenOCD/scripts -f  interface/cmsis-dap.cfg -f target/max32665.cfg`. Also check under **GDB Client Setup** is "Start GDB Session" checkbox checked.

Comment: @MarkU yeah my settings match all of what you stated, I opened a support line with Maxim and they said current drivers wont work for win11 not sure what  drivers though, if its the drivers in the embedded debugger or what. Mind you that in my linux environment everything works fine.